# how to check parent of current node is root node or not in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to check the parent of current node is root node or not in Xslt.How i do that?
Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for *correct* solutions, both in XPath 1.0 and in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `not(ancestor::*)`.

Usage Example:

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:if test="not(ancestor::*)">
      <xsl:message>The root element is "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>".</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Two qualifications: (a) this is OK for XSLT 1.0, where the root node is always the document node; it's not OK for 2.0, where the root node might be an element node (or indeed an attribute or text node). (b) The code given is OK except for the message. A comment or processing instruction that is a child of the root (document) node will satisfy the test, but produce a spurious message.

Comment: Nice xpath for identify root element, +1

Answer (score 9):

**In XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0)**:

```
not(parent::*)
```

Or you may use:

```
generate-id(..) = generate-id(/)
```

**In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0)**:

```
.. is root()
```